# Creating new instance of datacontext VS using Bindingsource

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I need to referesh binding source after inserting to linq to sql

I have tow solutions but I need real professional opinion about which one is better performance wise

1. Make a method that create a new instance of the datacontext and bind on this new instance (the perpous of the new instance is to avoid the cache)
2. Creating a bindingsource object and make it datasource the linq list and bind my gridview based on this bindingsource) and make the insert on this bindingsource.

Please help to take a dession

Comment: Are you trying to update a gridview or datagrid after you're inserting it to your SQL database?

Comment: Really I tried the following
1. datagridview.referesh();
2. Bindingsource.referesh();
3. datagridview.datasource = null; and rebind it again;
no one is going well.

Answer (score 0):

The bindings should be able to update themselves automatically as long as you send a notification that the content changed. You shouldn't attempt calls to Refresh() at all.

It all boils down to the way you handle the datasource and how you update it. If you're using an `ObservableCollection` as a datasource, adding items to it will update your UI with your new row automatically. If you're using custom objets, you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on them and throw notifications yourself that the binding will catch.

Maybe setting the binding mode to `TwoWay` will help too, although I think that's the default. Make sure you're not using OneWayToSource and OneWay, or Once.

Here's a simple tutorial with some examples: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26031/Simple-WPF-databinding-with-some-additional-WPF-go

If you need more help, pasting how you set your binding and how is the datasource created will help troubleshoot your issue.